# Has someone experiences with metrics for Design-By-Contract or can recommend metrics to measure the usage of Design-By-Contract in a code base?

Tags: metrics, code-contracts, design-by-contract

We are currently introducing Design-by-Contract to a software development group of about 60 developers, which are developing different components. We started by defining Design-By-Contract policies for C# and Java. To measure the progress we are counting the number of classes and the number of contract assertions (Preconditions, post conditions and invariants) with a simple search for keywords (excluding comments and string literals). So we have two statistics:

1. Number of contract assertions per
   component
2. Average number of contract assertions per class per component

Has someone experiences with metrics for Design-By-Contract or can recommend metrics to measure the usage of Design-By-Contract in a code base?

Comment: Just to clarify, what kind of metrics are you looking for. What is it that you want to measure?  do you just want to know that contracts are being used?

Comment: I'm looking for metrics, which tell me that contracts are "sufficiently" be used. We want to increase the code quality with contracts. If we see a team not implementing any contracts or only very few, we can support the team with training and consulting. The question is whether a component has enough contracts, so its understandability, maintainability aso. is best supported with 'Design by Contract'.

Comment: While it can give you an idea of how much it is used, it's better to check HOW it is used. Two well-defined contracts can say more than ten bad ones. Go after quality first, then quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first step should be code review of all new code that is checked in.

I can’t see an automated checking tool working until you have make it “normal” for all 
your programmers to use “Design-By-Contract”

Maybe include the results of the code reviews on the form that is filled in as part of the process of deciding if a programmer will get a  pay increase will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking on the contracts the same way you look at unit tests, try to measure the coverage of code by invariants and postconditions and number of checked arguments for preconditions.